# Python pdb is it possible to "go back in time"?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

When I am stepping through code using pdb, is it possible to go backwards or "back in time" into a previous program state.

E.g.

```
form l import f
x = 2
y = f(x)
z = y + 2
```

Let's say I step down to the last line

```
form l import f
x = 2
y = f(x)
z = y + 2  # <-----
```

And then I realize something is wrong, and I should've stepped into f instead. Instead of having to restart the pdb debugging process, can I go backwards?

```
form l import f
x = 2
y = f(x)   # <----- come here backwards, and then step into f
z = y + 2
```

That would be an amazingly powerful way to debug if so. I could probably get rid of most bugs in one pdb session if this were possible.

If this feature isn't implemented, how complex would it be to implement? I guess you need to save the entire python program state at each line (or just keep the last python state so we can go back at most 1 step).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There was a talk demonstrating this at EuroPython this year (I think it was a lightning talk)! I can't remember the name of it, but basically it `fork`ed a new process for every command, and suspended the old one. This means it can use a lot of memory, but it could do what you're describing but killing off the newer processes and reverting the display to the older suspended one. It was very fun to watch, but obviously has a lot of limitations and gotchas!

Comment: I think it was based on a fork of bpython, but I can't find anything about it now after some googling :-(